# CakePHP error: Call to a member function getColumnType()

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I'm trying to edit a record in the database, but the script gives me the following error:

**Fatal error: Call to a member function getColumnType() on a non-object in G:\wamp\www\a11\a\cake\libs\model\model.php on line 980**

The strange thing is, if I remove id from the form (so it creates a new record) it doesn't complain. That means that there's something wrong with the id column.

But what?

Just before the save I dump the array that is going to be saved:

```
Array
(
[Process] => Array
    (
        [id] => 5
        [oobject] => 1
        [oproperty] => Number
        [wproperty] => Payed
        [do] => somecode
        [active] => 1
        [name] => Testing
        [changed_user_id] => 3
        [selftrigger] => 1
    )

)
```

The saving code now looks like this:

```
$d = $this->data;
if ($this->Process->save($d)) {
```

`id` exists in the database

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id column is labeled "id" (without quotes), correct? If you are using MySQL, make sure that ID type is int (not any variation) and that it is the primary key with auto-increment. These settings are needed for the model class to function properly.

From this error, it looks like you have set the id column to something other than int.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Scott. It's set as bigint, primary key and auto_increment - just as all my other tables =/ Is there any cache files that I should know about? I deleted one in the tmp/cache/models directory, with no effect.

Comment: It has to be set as int, not big int. Cake will not recognize an id column when it is set to anything other than int.  Try setting the column to int and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: Check out this link to see the MySQL data types supported by cake... http://book.cakephp.org/view/1002/Creating-Database-Tables#Data-Type-Associations-by-Database-1003

Comment: Also be sure that the id does NOT allow nulls.

Comment: _int_ didn't solve the problem. I use bigint on several other tables in the database and that works great.

Comment: Actually, I now removed a debug() statement just before the code I pasted above, and that solved the problem. Thanks for your time, I appreciate it.

Comment: Glad you found the issue. Big int will "work" as your primary key, but the Cake Column Type will not be recognized as ID unless it is an int datatype. This only matters if you are using Cake specific functions to work with the id of a model.