# getting column names from a table in cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am trying to fetch column names from a table in cakephp, I tried the below code but it's not working.

```
$table_venue = $this->Venue->getColumnTypes();
print_r($table_venue);
//Venue is the model name .
```

When I execute the above code I get error as `Call to a member function getColumnTypes()`

and also I tried the below code

```
$table_venue = $this->query('Select columnname from venues');
print_r($table_venue);
```

Can you help me out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723635/cakephp-error-call-to-a-member-function-getcolumntype

Comment: `Call to a member function x on a non-object` means `$this->Venue` doesn't exist - the problem you have/had is loading/accessing the model.

Answer (score 1):

In a controller:

```
debug($this->Model->schema());
```

In a model:

```
debug($this->schema());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array_keys($this->Model->getColumnTypes());
```

Answer (score -1):

when you do this `$table_venue = $this->query('Select columnname from venues');`
do `$table_venue = $this->query('Select columnname from venues')->result_array();`
and store this in `$data` and echo `$data['columnname']`

Hope this helps.

Comment: `$this->query('Select columnname from venues')->result_array();` query returns an array, this code example is a fatal error.